# Preventing Max function from using timestamp as part of criteria on a date column in PL/SQL

Tags: datetime, plsql, oracle11g, max, truncate

If I query:

```
select max(date_created) date_created
```

on a datefield in PL/SQL (Oracle 11g), and there are records that were created on the same date but at different times, Max() returns only the latest times on that date.  What I would like to do is have the times be ignored and return ALL records that match the max date, regardless of their associated timestamp in that column.  What is the best practice for doing this?

Edit: what I'm looking to do is return all records for the most recent date that matches my criteria, regardless of varying timestamps for that day.  Below is what I'm doing now and it only returns records from the latest date AND time on that date.

```
    SELECT r."ID",
    r."DATE_CREATED"
  FROM schema.survey_response r
  JOIN
    (SELECT S.CUSTOMERID ,
      MAX (S.DATE_CREATED) date_created
    FROM schema.SURVEY_RESPONSE s
    WHERE S.CATEGORY IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
    ) recs
  ON R.CUSTOMERID    = recs.CUSTOMERID
  AND R.DATE_CREATED = recs.date_created
  WHERE R.CATEGORY  IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')
```

**Final Edit:** Got it working via the query below.

```
SELECT r."ID",
    r."DATE_CREATED"
  FROM schema.survey_response r
  JOIN
    (SELECT S.CUSTOMERID ,
      MAX (trunc(S.DATE_CREATED)) date_created
    FROM schema.SURVEY_RESPONSE s
    WHERE S.CATEGORY IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
    ) recs
  ON R.CUSTOMERID    = recs.CUSTOMERID
  AND trunc(R.DATE_CREATED) = recs.date_created
  WHERE R.CATEGORY  IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')
```

Comment: **WHAT** database - **WHICH** version .....

Comment: MAX only ever returns *a single scalar value* (so ignoring the non-date part of a datetime field is not relevant). Consider updating the post to *ask the real question*, such as "How can I select all records for the most recent day?" (Or what is appropriate -- this knowledge will also lead to better SO searches, as this question is quite "common".)

Comment: I apologize, more information is in order.  This is actually a PL/SQL query, and yes, I need to select all records for the most recent day.  This is for Oracle 11g.  Tags added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, you can get the latest date ignoring the time

```
SELECT max( trunc( date_created ) ) date_created
  FROM your_table
```

You can get all rows that have the latest date ignoring the time in a couple of ways.  Using analytic functions (preferrable)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               rank() over (order by trunc(date_created) desc) rnk
          FROM your_table a) 
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

or the more conventional but less efficient

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE trunc(date_created) = (SELECT max( trunc(date_created) )
                                FROM your_table)
```

Comment: Returned 0 records when I plugged the first block into my query.  I'm scared to even attempt to figure out how to incorporate the 2nd and 3rd blocks into my query.  `SELECT r."ID",
    r."DATE_CREATED"
  FROM schema.survey_response r
  JOIN
    (SELECT S.CUSTOMERID ,
      MAX (S.DATE_CREATED) date_created
    FROM schema.SURVEY_RESPONSE s
    WHERE S.CATEGORY IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
    ) recs
  ON R.CUSTOMERID    = recs.CUSTOMERID
  AND R.DATE_CREATED = recs.date_created
  WHERE R.CATEGORY  IN ('Yellow', 'Blue','Green')`

Comment: Got it working!  I neglected to wrap a trunc() around my join criteria for r.date_created to coincide with the truncation that I was doing with the Max() operation.  Have updated the final, working query in my original question. Thank you!!